# pyspark Collect causing memory to shoot up 80GB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark job that reads a CSV file and does a bunch of joins and renaming columns.
The file size is in MB

x = info_collect.collect()  
x size in python is around 100MB

however I get a memory crash, checking Gangla the memory goes up 80GB.
I have no idea why collection 100MB can cause memory to spike like that.

Could someone please advice?

Comment: Join can lead to multiplying the input  rows, which is probably happening in your case. 800 x 100MB = 80 GB. Check the joins if they are performed on unique keys.

Comment: yes I even checked the size of what was collected, it is only in MB.
the joins normally should not be happening inside the driver, it should be somewhere in the cluster and only the final results get to the driver, right?

Comment: Is there a way to debug this?